# Vim & Powershell - send selection to command

Tags: vim, powershell

I have a list in a file, and lets say I want to send it to the `sort` cmdlet (which is just for describing purposes, any cmdlet could act as a filter)

My vim shell setup is:

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-command
```

What I currently do is:

```
:.,.+5w c:\out.txt| r !cat c:\out.txt | sort
```

This works but its too verbose and I don't like I have to specify file name twice. Actually, I would like regular vim usage `:%!sort` but it displays error *"E485 - can't read file ... /Temp/Vi..tmp"*

It also fails sorting externally with `:w !sort`:

```
powershell -command "sort <C:/Users/MMILIC~1.ITR/AppData/Local/Temp/VIi696.tmp"
...
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

In this case the problem is that PowerShell doesn't support `<` redirection but I don't see any option in vim to configure it (apart from creating custom command and using VimL).

Comment: Did you try the internal `:sort`?

Comment: Sort was just an example. I need to use cmdlet as filter.

Answer (score 1):

No `<`? No problem! Use Vims `system()` function!

Vim Help:

```
 system({expr} [, {input}])
 Get the output of the shell command {expr}...
```

For sorting in particular I'd recommend Vims internal `sort` function. (`:h sort`)
Most of the time I use it on visual selections: select, `:sort<CR>`, done.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PowerShell Core as my default shell under Linux for the last few months, which was basically perfect, apart from this issue that was hindering my experience, but luckily after searching for the issue several times today I found a solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37860059/1831096

Basically, by disabling the use of a temporary file we can tell vim to use pipes, which work just as well in PowerShell! Put this in your `.vimrc` and be happy! ;)

```
set noshelltemp
```

For more information read this: [http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'shelltemp'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shelltemp%27)

Comment: I am using vscode now, but thx, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: I'm not a full time vim user either, but it still comes in handy from time to time, when it's just quicker to edit files from the command line, that's why I wanted to figure this out. ;)

Comment: You can start file from cli in vsocde too using `code <fn>` or edit stdin using `<bla>  | code -`.  There is no reason to open vim for this. Vim also doesn't work on remote powershell which makes its benefits regarding CLI dubious. Maybe on windows core  where no GUI is available. On linux it makes more sence.

Comment: I use this as a workaround because of a long lasting E485 Can't read file <path-to-temp-file> which happens when I use vim with PowerShell. Many thanks!